# Получение псевдонима указателя с неаллоцированной памятью

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Пишу простенькую реализацию бинарного дерева. Имею код:

```
void makeBinaryTree(BinaryTree *node, int numOfVertices) {
    while (0 < numOfVertices--) {
        auto accessoryPtr = node;
        while (nullptr == accessoryPtr) {
            if (static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX < 0.5) {
                accessoryPtr = accessoryPtr->left;//Тут
            } else {
                accessoryPtr = accessoryPtr->right;//и тут
            }
        }
        accessoryPtr = new BinaryTree;
        std::cout << "Enter value ";
        std::cin >> accessoryPtr->data;
    }
}
```

тут я циклично случайным образом выбираю, в какое место будет вставлена следующая вершина. Когда я нахожу вершину, у которой было выбрано пустое поддерево, равное `nullptr` (при создании вершины я сразу инициализирую его поддеревья `nullptr`) я хочу получить его псевдоним, выйти из цикла и выделить под него память.

В данном коде я лишь беру указатель, соответственно, после выделения памяти под `accessoryPtr`, он будет указывать в какое то другое место памяти, и на `node` это никак не повлияет.

Как вариант, можно было бы написать функцию:

```
void makeNodeOfBinaryTree(BinaryTree *&node) {
    node = new BinaryTree;
    std::cout << "Enter value ";
    std::cin >> node->data;
}
```

и, тогда, ветка, в которой я хотел получить псевдоним указателя будет выглядеть так:

```
if (accessoryPtr->left == nullptr) {
    makeNodeOfBinaryTree(accessoryPtr->left);
    break;
}
accessoryPtr = accessoryPtr->left;
```

однако дальше по коду я вновь встречаюсь с подобной проблемой и там такое решение уже не подойдёт. В идеале, конечно, переписать всё нормально, но уже просто интересно разобраться, есть ли возможность получения требуемого мне псевдонима?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему тут просто не хватает еще одного уровня перенаправления.

```
assert(nullptr != p_node);
auto pp_node{::std::addressof(p_node));
do
{
    if(0 == (static_cast<unsigned int>(rand()) bitand 1u))
    {
        pp_node = ::std::addressof((**pp_node).left);
    }
    else
    {
        pp_node = ::std::addressof((**pp_node).right);
    }
} while(nullptr != (*pp_node));
(*pp_node) = new BinaryTree;
```

Ну и еще условие `while (nullptr == accessoryPtr)` не может быть правильным так как если accessoryPtr не ноль, то цикл не будет выполнятся, а если ноль - то внутри цикла он будет разыменован.